# How to remove this line in language C : "Program ended with exit code: 0"

Tags: c

I wrote a code in C and it executed perfectly but at the end I got a line saying "Program ended with exit code: 0". What does this line signify and how do I get rid of this?

Comment: Do not use the IDE  for program execution.

Comment: If you're running the code from within an IDE or other managed environment, it will usually show the exit status of the program.  If you invoke the program directly from the command line, you will not see the message.  An exit code of 0 usually signifies that the program exited normally.

Comment: Normally you see this for command line type programs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what it means is that the program ran without any error. A **0** usually says that the program executed properly. Any nonzero number denotes some problem. Use text editors such as emacs or vim   etc. and compile and execute your program.

Answer (score 4):

**What it is?**

an exit code of 0 indicates no  error. If a program wants to
    indicate there was something wrong when it exited it will exit with
    a non-zero value.

**How to get rid of it?**

Do not use the IDE for program execution. –  as [BLUEPIXY](https://stackoverflow.com/users/971127/bluepixy) said.

Answer (score 2):

The message doesn't come from your program itself, but from the IDE (e.g. Visual Studio) that launches the program. Try launching it from the command-line or by double-clicking the .exe file.

The meaning of "exit code 0" is usually: Everything went fine, the program exited successfully. Other exit codes usually stand for aborts because of errors and the actual number gives a hint about the type of error that occurred.