# Program displays ended with exit code 0;

Tags: c++

I'm trying to complete this program for class assignment. Pretty much the program displays all the requirements. However, I'm getting a Program ended with exit code:0 added to the output. I checked the code, but I didn't find the error. Can someone tells me how can I remove this message?
Thanks for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()

{
    string fname, middle, last;
    cout << "Enter a name in the format First Middle Last:" <<endl;
    cin >> fname >> middle >> last;
    cout << fname  << endl;
    cout << middle << endl;
    cout << last <<endl;

    string fname2 = fname.substr (0,1);
    cout <<fname2 ;
    string middle2 = middle.substr (0,1);
    cout <<middle2;
    string last2= last.substr (0,1);
    cout <<last2 <<endl;
    string middle3 = middle.substr (0,3);
    cout << middle3 <<endl;
    string fullname = fname + " " + middle + "" + last + " ";
    string fullname2 = fullname.substr (7,1);
    cout << fullname2 <<endl;
    string fullname4 = fullname;
    cout << fullname.length() <<endl;

}
```

This is the output:

```
Enter a name in the format First Middle Last:
Program ended with exit code: 0
Robert anthony Plant
Robert
anthony
Plant
RaP
ant
a
20
```

Comment: it probably be added by your IDE. If you run it through command line, I would expect that message disappear.

Comment: What development environment and editor are you using? I have seen buffering issue like that in CLion. In CLion it have to do with how they handle the output when running the program and their own internal buffering.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove this line in language C : "Program ended with exit code: 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669825/how-to-remove-this-line-in-language-c-program-ended-with-exit-code-0)

Comment: I'm using Xcode to complete this C++ program, I stared from zero again but the first output displays program ended with exit code :  0 anyway.

Comment: Exiting with code 0 is what you would expect with a `return 0;`at the end of `main`. Since `main` returns nothing, C++ assumes and returns 0 for you.

Comment: Thanks so much. command line is giving me not error.

Comment: thanks so much for your answers, I run the program through command line. Message is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Exit code 0 means that the program completed successfully. If everything that happened was exactly what you wanted (besides the exit code message), then you're fine. All correct programs will end with an exit code 0, if there is another error or exit code then that is where there might be a programming problem. It could also have something to do with what platform, IDE, or compiler you are using to run your code.