# C language: When I use scanf the output console displays "Program ended with exit code: 0[whatever I input for scanf]" How do I fix this?

Tags: c, scanf, exit-code

For example:

```
printf("Please enter the amount of money you want to accumulate: ");
scanf("%f", &cashGoal);
printf("You would like to save up to $%.2f\n", cashGoal);
```

Returns this:

```
Please enter the amount of money you want to accumulate: Program ended with exit code: 0123123
You would like to save up to $123123.00
```

Edit: Here's the full code, it's my homework project so it's a little long

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

FILE *fp;

#define PENNY 0.01

int daystoCashGoal(float);

int main(void) {
fp = fopen("csis.txt", "w");
float cashGoal;


printf("Please enter the amount of money you want to accumulate: ");
fprintf(fp, "Please enter the amount of money you want to accumulate: ");
scanf("%f", &cashGoal);
printf("\n");
fprintf(fp,"\n");
printf("You would like to accumulate $%.2f.\n\n", cashGoal);
fprintf(fp, "You would like to accumulate $%.2f.\n\n", cashGoal);

daystoCashGoal(cashGoal);

fclose(fp);
return 0;
}

//Calculates the number of days it will take to accumulate the user-desired amount, doubles the deposit for each day, and sums up the balance for each day
int daystoCashGoal(float cashGoal){
int day = 1;
float dailyBalance = 0, dailyDeposit;

printf("DAY          DEPOSIT          BALANCE\n");
fprintf(fp, "DAY          DEPOSIT          BALANCE\n");
printf("___          _______          _______\n");
fprintf(fp, "___          _______          _______\n");

 while (dailyBalance <= cashGoal) {
    dailyDeposit = (pow( 2, day - 1)) * PENNY;
    dailyBalance += dailyDeposit;

    printf("%3d %5s %10.2f %5s %10.2f\n", day,"", dailyDeposit,"", dailyBalance);
    fprintf(fp, "%3d %5s %10.2f %5s %10.2f\n", day,"", dailyDeposit,"", dailyBalance);

     if (dailyBalance <= cashGoal) {
                 day ++;
     }
     else if (dailyBalance >= cashGoal) {
         continue;
     }

}

if (dailyBalance >= cashGoal) {
    printf("\nIt took %d days to accumulate at least $%.2f.\n", day, cashGoal);
    fprintf(fp, "\nIt took %d days to accumulate at least $%.2f.\n", day, cashGoal);
}

return day;
}
```

I'm not looking for advice on the rest of my code since this project has already been graded, but the exit code issue is affecting the rest of my projects and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks

Comment: What are you returning at the end of main?

Comment: Show the full code please. BTW, what is your environment? Looks like some buffering glitch.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Many IDEs print this line when the program ends (e.g., Visual Studio).  Odd that it would appear before the printed results, though.  This would not happen running from command line.  As a workaround in the IDE, try adding "fflush(stdout);" before exiting the program.  Also possibly try "sleep(1);" after the fflush.  But please do create a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For example, this behavior would be caused if you have a fork/exec in your program (which I doubt you're using, but we hate to guess.)

Comment: @EugeneSh. I'm using Xcode

Comment: Try running the compiled executable stand-alone

Comment: FYI, to enter code, paste it in, select it, and click the `{}` widget.  This shifts it right 4 spaces, causing it to be rendered as code.  When run from the command line, the output is ordered as expected (and there is no "Program ended" line.)  So, this is an artifact of Xcode and you can ignore it or workaround as I suggested using `fflush` and `sleep`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove this line in language C : "Program ended with exit code: 0"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32669825/how-to-remove-this-line-in-language-c-program-ended-with-exit-code-0)